# Boolean in while-loop

Tags: function, if-statement, while-loop

I do not understand the excecution of my below code.
I'm using python as programming language.

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  while n % 2 == 0:
    if n == 0:
      return False
    n = n / 2
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False

print(is_power_of_two(9))
```

So when I pass 9 to my function, why does my code execute it as false? 9 by 2 has a remainder of 1. Therefore the while-code should not be executed, because the condition is that the number has no remainder. With the if-statement the condition is that a number has a remainder of 1, which is true for the number 9. therefore the function should execute my number as "True".

I just want to know why python declares the 9 as False and not True.

Comment: Which programming language is this? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I'm using Python. sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, including your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I do not have a problem directly. I just want to know why python executes the code the way it does.

Comment: "why python declares the 9 as False and not True" - it does not. Have you checked the intermediate steps of your algorithm?

Comment: If I enter this code in python compiler, python prints it out as „False“ and this is my question…

Comment: Then why not check **why** this happens? For example, you could print `n` in each iteration, and compare that to the value you expect to see there

Comment: Hello Nico, thank you for your tip. I printed my function with the number 8 and everything was understandable why 9 is False. I totally forgot the looping of the while-function. I thought in the n-variable inside the if-statement is the remainder of your number stored.